# Windows 10 Pro randomly created another copy of C drive. What's going on?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, duplicate

I recently just noticed something strange. My C drive has somehow duplicated itself as the B drive.

[image: B drive and C Drive are the same]

[image: The B drive has a bunch of nonsense files. I don't remember creating them.]

Has anyone encountered this? How do I get rid of the B drive?

Comment: What you describe does not happen randomly. What did you add to Windows to cause this?

Comment: What you see is most likely the result of using `subst`. The filenames kind of hints at this too. Are you using KoboldAI?

Comment: Try in CMD the command `subst B: /d`

Comment: I am using Kobold ai

Comment: @DanielB what is KoboldAI and why does that matter?

Comment: @user253751 Because that’s what’s creating the drive and also what is in the directory/drive.

Comment: huh, weird... why the heck would they design it like that?

Answer (score 0):

This (virtual) drive is the result of using [`subst`](https://ss64.com/nt/subst.html), a very old command that takes a directory and makes it appear as a drive, with drive letter and all. Because this virtual drive is still physically located on another (C: in your case), it shows the same free/used space. You can remove it using `subst B: /D`. This is also what the batch file [`disconnect-kobold-drive.bat`](https://github.com/KoboldAI/KoboldAI-Client/blob/main/disconnect-kobold-drive.bat) does.

[KoboldAI](https://github.com/KoboldAI/KoboldAI-Client), which is what’s on the drive in the screenshot, creates this drive (and/or K:) to work around problems with long path names and/or spaces in path names.